# javascript function to multiply values and sum column in table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have a simple html table where the user enters two values in each row.
As they enter data I need the table to automatically multiply the two values in each row and produce the value at the end of the row.
At the same time it should give a running total at the bottom of the table.

I have got the function multiplying values as they are entered but my total always remains zero.  I have gone wrong somewhere and just can't see it anymore.

Can you help?

```js
function add_to_total(el) {

  var parent = $(el).closest('tr');
  var price = parent.find('.price').val() == "" ? 1 : parent.find('.price').val();
  var qty = parent.find('.qty').val() == "" ? 1 : parent.find('.qty').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  var total = total.toFixed(2);
  parent.find('.total_price').val(total);

  var gtot = 0;

  $("#quantum tr > tbody td:nth-child(3)").each(
    (_, el) => gtot += Number($(el).text()) || 0
  );

  $("#sum1").text(gtot);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="quantum" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable " role="grid">

  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Multiplier</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th>Past Losses</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>Earnings</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr price" name="" pr_id="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr qty" name="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="" class="pr total_price" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Pension</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr price" name="" pr_id="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr qty" name="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 26px">
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" name="" class="pr total_price" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Care</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr price" name="" pr_id="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 200px; height: 26px"> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr qty" name="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="" class="pr total_price" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>

      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Total Damages</th>
      <th id="sum1" type="number"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: You're putting the product in `.val()`, but then adding `.text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.text()` to get the value of an input.

Loop over the `.total_price` elements and add their values.

```js
function add_to_total(el) {

  var parent = $(el).closest('tr');
  var price = parent.find('.price').val() == "" ? 1 : parent.find('.price').val();
  var qty = parent.find('.qty').val() == "" ? 1 : parent.find('.qty').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  var total = total.toFixed(2);
  parent.find('.total_price').val(total);

  var gtot = 0;

  $(".total_price").each(
    (_, el) => gtot += Number(el.value) || 0
  );

  $("#sum1").text(gtot);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="quantum" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable " role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Multiplier</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Past Losses</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Earnings</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr price" name="" pr_id="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr qty" name="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="" class="pr total_price" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Pension</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr price" name="" pr_id="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr qty" name="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 26px">
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" name="" class="pr total_price" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Care</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr price" name="" pr_id="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 200px; height: 26px"> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="pr qty" name="" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 26px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="" class="pr total_price" style="width: 200px; height: 26px">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Total Damages</th>
      <th id="sum1" type="number"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: @BrandonBuck Why is that needed? The Stack Snippet works.

Comment: Brandon Buck thanks so much, you sorted me out in a matter of minutes.  A quick and simple solution that works very elegantly.

Comment: I did nothing, credit goes to @Barmar for the quick response. As to why I made a fiddle, you can actually play around with the fiddle a lot easier than the StackSnippet. So it's great for visualizing quickly but to dig further a fiddle is nice to have. At least in my opinion. You can simply ignore the fiddle if you don't believe so.